# 2 Request Handlers for POST (ResponseBody + "Normal")

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I like to implement a REST-API into my SpringMVC application. At the moment, I have one method to handle POST-Requests, which "returns" a rendered ViewScript.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(User user, Model model)
{
    return "success";
}
```

It would be nice, to add a second method with the @ResponseBody Annotation for POST-Requests, e.g. to send a JSON-Response.
Furthermore, the old Method still has to exists, to handle "normal" Requests.

But a code like this doesn't work:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(User user, Model model)
{
    return "success";
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object add(User user, Model model)
{
    // [...]
    return myObject;
}
```

With this code, I'm getting a 405 (Method Not Allowed) Error from Tomcat. How can I fix this?

Comment: It is a post method call , When you directly hit a request in the browser. It will produce like that 405 error. To check your service in the browser use the following tool https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, Spring has no way to differentiate between these two requests: same URL, same request method.

You can further differentiate by mimetype:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, headers="content-type=application/json")
```

Although there are several mimetypes associated with JSON :/ The `headers` value takes an array, however, so you can narrow/widen it as necessary.

See the [`headers` docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#headers%28%29).

Comment: Is it possible to define an own Annotation like @ RestRequestMapping, that extends from @ RequestMapping, but automatically sets the expected headers? So that I don't have to specify them at each method?

Comment: Or is there a more intelligent way than defining two methods?

Comment: @Markus Annotations can't be subclassed, so not trivially.

Comment: Do you now a more appropriate way to meet my target?

Answer (score 0):

Dont USE TWO ANNOTATION. It is a poor option. Just have one more method without annotation. But the method from the old method by checking the below condition.

JUST PASS ONE MORE ARGUMENT FROM UI by query parameter(request="JSON_Request").

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(User user, Model model)
{
    if(request="JSON_Request") {
       newMethod(user, model);
    }
    return "success";
}


  private Object newMethod(User user, Model model)
{
    // [...]
    return myObject;
}
```